# ffmpeg and boost::asio NULL pointer

Tags: c++, boost, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a special video software which will run on multiple core machines.

I want many c++ object to stream video files and many other c++ objects to store the streamed data into file.

I have created some simple classes, but when I try to create 2 and more objects I got:

```
opening stream9079.sdp
[udp @ 0xaef5380] bind failed: Address already in use
Could not open input file stream9079.sdp
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I use only one object everything is fine.

I use the following code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::io_service ios1;

    Channel *channels[100];

    channels[0] = new Channel(ios, 9078, atoi(argv[1]));
    channels[0]->StartTimer(0);

    channels[1] = new Channel(ios1, 9079, atoi(argv[1]));
    channels[1]->StartTimer(0);

    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&worker, &ios));
    boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&worker, &ios1));


    t.join();
    t1.join();

    CEVLOG_MSG << "done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My `Channel` class implementation is:

```
#include "channel.hpp"
#include "utils.hpp"
#include "boost/lexical_cast.hpp"
Channel::Channel(boost::asio::io_service &ioP, int i, bool to_send):
    Runnable(ioP),
    work( new boost::asio::io_service::work(ioP) ),
    ofmt(NULL),
    ifmt_ctx(NULL),
    ofmt_ctx(NULL)
{
    id = i;
    sender = to_send;

    if (sender)
    {
            input.assign("/home/georgi/Downloads/video/IMG_0019.MOV");
            output.assign("rtp://10.101.3.60:"); output += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(id);
    }
    else
    {
            input.assign("stream"); input += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(id); input += ".sdp";
            output.assign("test"); output += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(id); output += ".mp4";
    }

video_idx = audio_idx = sub_idx = -1;

    if (OpenInput())
    {
            if (sender)
                    OpenOutput(eStreamOutput);
            else
                    OpenOutput(eFileOutput);
    }
}

 Channel::~Channel()
 {
    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);

    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);

    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
            avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);

    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

    work.reset();
}

bool Channel::OpenInput()
{
    CEVLOG_MSG << "opening " << input << std::endl;

    int ret;
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, input.c_str(), 0, 0)) < 0)
    {
            CEVLOG_ERR << "Could not open input file " << input << std::endl;
            return false;
    }

    CEVLOG_MSG << " " << ifmt_ctx << std::endl;

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0)
    {
            CEVLOG_ERR << "Failed to retrieve input stream information" << std::endl;
            return false;
    }

    ifmt_ctx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_GENPTS;

    //read and set timestamps to 0
av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);
pkt.pts = pkt.dts = 0;

return true;
}

bool Channel::OpenOutput(tOutputType WhatToOpen)
{
    int SDP_size;

    switch (WhatToOpen)
    {
    case eFileOutput:
            avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, output.c_str());
            break;

    case eStreamOutput:
            avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, "rtp", output.c_str());

            char SDP[4096];
            SDP_size = 4096;

            av_sdp_create(&ofmt_ctx, 1, SDP, SDP_size);
            CEVLOG_DBG << "SDP=" << SDP << std::endl;
            break;

    default:
            assert(false);
            break;
    }

    if (!ofmt_ctx)
    {
            CEVLOG_ERR << "Could not create output context" << std::endl;
            return false;
    }

    ofmt = ofmt_ctx->oformat;

    video_idx = FindIndex(AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
            if (avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, output.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0)
            {
                    CEVLOG_ERR << "Could not open output file " << output << std::endl;
                    return false;
            }
    }

    if (avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL) < 0)
    {
            CEVLOG_ERR << "Error occurred when opening output file " << output << std::endl;
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

unsigned int Channel::FindIndex(AVMediaType Type)
{
    int idx;

    for (idx = 0; idx < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; idx++)
    {
            if (ifmt_ctx->streams[idx]->codec->codec_type == Type)
            {
                    AVStream *in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[idx];
                    AVStream *out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);

                    if (!out_stream)
                    {
                            CEVLOG_ERR << "Failed allocating output stream" << std::endl;
                            break;
                    }

                    if (avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec) < 0)
                    {
                            CEVLOG_ERR << "Failed to copy context from input to output stream codec context" << std::endl;
                            break;
                    }

                    out_stream->codec->codec_tag = 0;
                    if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
                    {
                            out_stream->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
                    }

                    break;
            }
    }

    return idx;
 }

void Channel::Callback()
{
    if (sender)
            SendVideo();
    else
            RecvVideo();
}

void Channel::SendVideo()
{
    int ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);
    int time_ms = 0;

    if (ret != 0)
    {
            av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
            work.reset();
            return;
    }

    if (pkt.stream_index == video_idx)
    {
            AVStream *in_stream  = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
            AVStream *out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];

            AVRational time_base = ifmt_ctx->streams[video_idx]->time_base;

            char timestamp[100];
            time_ms = 1000 * 1000 * strtof(timestamp2char(timestamp, pkt.duration, &time_base), NULL);

            pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF);
            pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF);
            pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
            pkt.pos = -1;

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt);

            if (ret < 0)
            {
                    CEVLOG_ERR << "Error muxing packet" << std::endl;
                    return;
            }
    }

    av_free_packet(&pkt);

    StartTimer(time_ms);
}

void Channel::RecvVideo()
{
    int ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
            //Some error or end of stream is detected. Write file trailer
            av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
            work.reset();
            return;
    }

    //if is NOT video just continue reading
    if (pkt.stream_index == video_idx)
    {
            AVStream *in_stream  = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
            AVStream *out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];

            AVRational time_base = ifmt_ctx->streams[video_idx]->time_base;

            pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF);
            pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF);
            pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
            pkt.pos = -1;

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                    CEVLOG_ERR << "Error muxing packet" << std::endl;
                    return;
            }
    }

    av_free_packet(&pkt);

    StartTimer(0);
}
```

Comment: there's too much of the wrong code. Nothing is complete. Just reduce the code until you find the culprit. Or not, and then post the SSCCE

Answer (score 0):

I don't know those libraries but what it looks like is that you're multiply grabbing ports 9078 and 9079.

Comment: The program is started twice:
once as sender and once as receiver

Comment: Did you check that that 'sender' variable is coming out true or false according to how you start it? The error message is clearly saying that two things are called stream9079.sdp.

Comment: Yes, I did check it. 2 receiving channels and 2 sending
./videogw 0 #receiver
./videogw 1 #sender

Comment: Ah. Looked a bit more closely now. The crash happens in avformat_open_input of Channel::OpenInput on channels[1] when you pass zero for the parameter. It's trying to grab a port. Why does it want a port? It looks to me like it should only be bouncing files around.

Comment: It needs  to open port to read the video network stream which is meant to be stored into a file. But something strange is happening and this action is not performed. I looked into ffmpeg source coude but...it is too complicatted...That is the reason I asked for help

Comment: If it's reading from some other server then it would normally choose a random LOCAL port (although the remote port has to be the one they're publishing on) and there'd be no shortage. Are you doing anything to force it into using a specific local port?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote simple code
Now I have a crash in the libs.
Probably there is some issue
I posted a question the ffmpeg maillst
https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2015-April/008023.html

I submitted an issue in ffmpeg tracking system
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4458